# Event calling sequence in application designer in peoplecode

Tags: peoplesoft

As there are following event sets in Peoplecode

- Record Field,
- Component Record Field,
- Component Record,
- Component, etc.

And also they contain events which are common in one or more event sets like
field change event is present in both Record Field and Component Record Field..

Then in this case if we have written the field change event, from whose event set does this event gets called?

Answer (score 0):

The "PeopleSoft Component Processor Flow Chart" is very helpful for determining the sequence of PeopleCode events.

http://peoplesoftcomponentprocessorflowchart.blogspot.com/

A basic flow of useful PeopleCode events when component is first loaded are:

1. Search Record - SearchInit
2. Search Record - SearchSave
3. Component - PreBuild
4. Record Field - FieldDefault
5. Record Field - FieldFormula
6. Record Field - RowInit
7. Component - PostBuild
8. Page - Activate

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I would prefer uploading the image but one needs 10 reputation to do so... I have updated my answer to be more descriptive as to where you can find the image.